# EntityFramework through Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, app-config

I have a class library called `DataManip`, a webform project and a winform project.

`DataManip` is a class that will contain all the necessary methods to manipulate the database, including handling migrations and database updates.

The `.mdf` database is also inside the `DataManip` project.

The problem that I am having right now, is that when I setup a connection string in the `App.config` file of `DataManip`, it doesn't recognize the |DataDirectory| substitution string.

Connection string :

`<add name="Context" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DB\mydatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Harcoding the path in AttachDbFilename will successfully generate the database, but working with team members make this approach not possible.

The error message that I get when I try to run `update-database` in `DataManip` is :

`A file activation error occured. The physical file name '\DB\mydatabase.mdf' may be incorrect...`

How can I get the DataDirectory substitution string to work in a class library?

Comment: You should put this connection string in the web.config of the webform project and maybe in the App.config of the windows form project

Comment: The point of DataManip is that both the webform project and the winform project can use the same class to access the same data. Therefore, changing something in DataManip will affect both projects.

Comment: `|DataDirectory|` means different things depending on the application that runs it. For Winforms, its the executable directory, for web apps, its the App_Data folder. You can set the directory using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", PathToNewDataDirectory)` if you want, but this would have to be taken care of before the connection string is read from the config file.

Comment: @Ron Beyer How about |DataDirectory| for Class libraries?

Comment: It depends on the context of which the library is loaded. For web apps, App_Data, for Winforms/Desktop, its the exe directory. Thats the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` part.

Comment: Also, since paths are relative, for exe projects this just replaces the `|DataDirectory|` with an empty string, making it relative to your application root, which is why its searching in `<path to your exe>\DB\mydatabase.mdf`.

Comment: @RonBeyer How would I run C# code before loading the App.config file?

Comment: You don't, and the app.config file is not "loaded" per se. The settings are read out on-demand, they are not loaded once at startup and kept in memory. Each time the configuration manager is requested a value, it reads it from the file, which is why you can change app.config files at runtime without restarting the app. So any place you change the setting before the setting is requested, then it will reflect the new value. A logical place to do this is in the program.cs file before the first form is shown.